# Fatal error: 'breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h' file not found

Tags: crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps, crashlytics-android, google-breakpad

I'm integrating Google BreakPad library into my Android Project. Below the steps, I'm following to generate a mini-dump file for Crash at run time.
Please check and let me know if I'm on the correct path:

steps1: I have taken a clone for Google Breakpad client repo from (https://github.com/google/breakpad)

Step2:  I have added Breakpad main library folder and google-breakpad folder into the Android project directory and  JNI folder and move (Andoid.mk, Application.mk, test-break pad.CPP) files into JNI

Step3:  I have created the Gradle Task to build NDK and bind with project build.
Inside test-break pad.CPP we have included two header files from a breakpad-main directory. Below is the included directory path.

#include "breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h"
#include "breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h"

While ndk-build we are facing below Error:
**jni/test_breakpad.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h' file not found
#include "breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [C:/Users/gurmeet.singh1/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/build//../build/core/build-binary.mk:478: obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs-debug/test_google_breakpad/test_breakpad.o] Error 1

If I'll update absoulate patch into relative path
#include "../breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h"
#include "../breakpad-main/src/client/linux/handler/exception_handler.h"**

then we are facing path issue inside  minidump_descriptor.h or  exception_handler.h files.

Please guide us on how we can proceed ahead to generate the minidump file for Crashstack trace?